# How can I get Audiere to output to a file?

Tags: c#, .net, file, audio

My (C#, .NET) application uses the [Audiere library](http://audiere.sourceforge.net/) for audio output.

The requirements have grown to include output to a file (i.e. wav or mp3). Is there anyway for Audiere to do this natively? Or is there a way to capture its output and write it to a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else finds this question, I ended up not using Audiere. I used this question: [Writing musical notes to a wav file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974531/writing-musical-notes-to-a-wav-file)