# How to generate different sound frequencies?

Tags: ada

I'd either like to export to file or play live sound frequencies. How?

The equivalent in C#

```
Console.Beep(1, 1);n//Beep 1Hz for 1ms
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing musical notes to a wav file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974531/writing-musical-notes-to-a-wav-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ada standard does not include a sound API, but there are libraries which can help you.  Those that I know of:

- [ALSA binding](http://repositories.jacob-sparre.dk/alsa-binding) - records and plays back sound on a Linux system
- [libao binding](http://adi.thur.de/index_old_asound.html) - sound library for ESD, OSS, Solaris, and IRIX.

If you really just need a plain beep on the console, this should work on all ANSI compatible consoles:

```
with Ada.Characters.Latin_1,
     Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Beep is
begin
   Ada.Text_IO.Put (Ada.Characters.Latin_1.BEL);
end Beep;
```

Comment: Shameless plug: There is also oto - which is binding to OpenAL - https://github.com/darkestkhan/oto